# Comparison with possibly non-existent properties

Tags: javascript, properties, boolean, undefined

My background is more in strongly-typed languages than not, so I will state up front that I have a bias against treating undefined objects in a casual manner. That said, I was considering a simple question of assigning a Boolean value to a variable, where said Boolean comes from the property of some object, and while the object will always exist the property may not.

That sounds more complicated than it really is. Take a look. We start with spinning up some objects early in the code, covering the three possible scenarios:

```
var object1 = {};
object1.IsDisplayed = true;
var object2 = {};
object2.IsDisplayed = false;
var object3 = {};
// notice we do *not* create the IsDisplayed property here
```

Sometime later we call the process() function that takes a single argument. Let's call this baseline Solution A.

### Solution A

This being JavaScript, that actually works as expected for object1, object2, and object3. But it seems to have a bit of a code smell to me; it is not clear that the author has considered a possibly non-existent property.

```
function process(renderedItem) {
    var rendered = renderedItem.IsDisplayed;
    if (rendered) {
        // do some stuff here
    }
}
```

I see two possible ways to make this more robust:

### Solution B

I like this solution because it is both robust and clear to even the most casual reader that the undefined case has been properly considered. On the downside it is wordy, not nearly as compact as solution C, and it uses a string name of a property, which I have a strong distaste for.

```
function process(renderedItem) {
    var rendered = renderedItem.hasOwnProperty('IsDisplayed')
        ? renderedItem.IsDisplayed
        : false;
    if (rendered) {
        // do some stuff here
    }
}
```

### Solution C

I like this solution because it is robust and compact; it explicitly takes into account a possibly non-existent property; however, it is not nearly as obvious as solution B. I remember early on reading some colleagues' code and thinking,"What the heck?" and suggested deleting the `=== true` as redundant. Also, it still is technically referencing an undefined value (in the case of passing in object3).

```
function process(renderedItem) {
    var rendered = renderedItem.IsDisplayed === true;
    if (rendered) {
        // do some stuff here
    }
}
```

Is there a clear "best practice" amongst these three variations?

Comment: Each time I was asking similar **best practice** question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ I was told it's not appropriate and I should include the full code :)

Comment: About the **Solution A**: *it is not clear that the author has considered a possibly non-existent property* - non-existent property is ```undefined```, the ```if``` statement has ```falsy``` value... It looks good to me actually!

Comment: I'd say using `hasOwnProperty` is the best solution if you want to check for _existence_. Not sure why -- "and it uses a string name of a property, which I have a strong distaste for" -- is distasteful. There is absolutely no difference between `o.a` and `o['a']`; all object keys are strings.

Comment: I'd prefer this variation on C: `var rendered = renderedItem.IsDisplayed;
    if (rendered === true) {` followed by C, then A.

Comment: You may do like `!!object.property` and get the Boolean of the property being falsey ot truty. However if the property is 0 you will get false so keep in mind there is that..

Comment: So called "best practice" questions aren't really on–topic here as they lead to very opinionated answers. At least you've provided some criteria for "best". The main question is whether you care about the difference between the property having a falsey value vs not existing. If that matters, then C suits. If not, A is fine. What other criteria for "best practice" do you suggest? If it really bothers you, initialise the value to *false*.

Comment: You can avoid using the string name by checking the property's type instead: `rendered = typeof renderedItem.IsDisplayed !== "undefined"`